# How to find then copy found files, linux

Tags: linux, wsdl

I'm trying to search a directory for all of its wsdl files and then copy them to another location. Right now I'm using `xargs` since, if I understand correctly, it takes the output of one command and uses it as the arguments of the piped command. However, I keep getting prompted that a file is not a directory and thus the command fails. I'm fairly new to linux so maybe someone can tell me why this is happening and how to fix it?

Here's my command:

`find VMware-vSphere-SDK-5.5.0-1284541/ -iname "*.wsdl" | xargs cp -i '{}' /home/jaayers`

Keeps throwing this:

`cp: target ‘VMware-vSphere-SDK-5.5.0-1284541/SDK/eam/wsdl/eam.wsdl’ is not a directory`

**EDIT:**

So changing the command to

`find VMware-vSphere-SDK-5.5.0-1284541/ -iname "*.wsdl" | xargs cp -i {} -t /home/jaayers`

will copy the files but still prints this message

`cp: cannot stat ‘{}’: No such file or directory`

so even though it's doing what I want it to do I assume it's not the proper way to achieve the desired function, perhaps someone can suggest a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to be inside the folder , or give the absolute path I think like "/home/user/VMware-vSphere-SDK-5.5.0-1284541/"